# tachyons.io: emphasize a single word in italics

Tags: html, italics, tachyons-css

## My problem

I am using the [tachyons.io](http://tachyons.io/) framework to style an HTML page. I would like to emphasize a single word in a sentence with *italics* fonts, without discontinuing the sentence flow by a line break.

## The manual

[The manual](http://tachyons.io/docs/typography/font-style/) suggests using `<p class="i"></p>`, but using `p` adds a line break.

## What have I tried

Apart from reading the manual, I tried using an internal `p class="i"` or `class="i"`. The former broke the sentence with a new line, the latter did not change the word style.

## My question

How can I emphasize a single word with *italics* in [tachyons.io](http://tachyons.io/), without breaking the sentence with a newline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [`<span>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span): `<span class="i"> ... </span>`.

(or, alternatively, an [`<i>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/i).)

Example:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tachyons/4.9.1/tachyons.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<p>
Only one <span class="i">word</span> is in Italics here.
</p>

<p>
Can also use <i>plain HTML</i> for that.
</p>
```